AST Node Builder and evaluating with Query builder or Aggration Formulas
I wonder can make an AST Builder using Syncfusion blazor query builder. For example, the following .net libraries help me create and evaluate AST nodes.
https://github.com/aprismatic/prismadb-queryast
https://github.com/seesharper/DbExpressions
And my second question is can i create aggreation func. rules like SUM, MAX, MIN, AVG, COUNT etc.
Basically i want to build decesion engine based on this rules.
Basic scenario :
Check if any transaction exceeds €150,000.
Check if the total amount of this month's transactions is 150% of the previous month's total amount.
Check if any transaction was sent to a blacklisted country.
Check if the user has been a customer for more than 2 years.
or
3 or more success transactions within 1 hour at the same merchant with the same card. (Excluding BINs 123456, 234567, 345678)
